# unexpected token при написании класса

Tags: java

Я создала класс Square, где динамическому массиву list хочу добавить элементы. Но выходит такая ошибка. Не понимаю из-за чего

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Square {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        list.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: имела в виду list.add(i);

Comment: @Kromster, `[edit]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так вы в корне класса метод пишете, так нельзя. Нужно внутри метода делать.

```
class Square {
    public void add() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            list.add(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Если список нужно сохранить на будущее, то объявить его можно в теле класса:

```
class Square {
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            list.add(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В классе можно создавать переменные, поэтому выражение

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

вполне допустимо,

А вот цикл `for`  не может быть свойством класса, для того чтобы код выполнялся, его надо поместить в блок или метод, или конструктор. Если компилятор находит слово/токен `for` и он не там стоит, то выдаёт такую ошибку. Синтаксические ошибки обычно помечаются красным цветом, указывая в какой строке и каком столбце стоит неверное слово.